# Magento 2 different routes per store view

Tags: store-view, router, routes, magento24

I have one online store with two store views, English and French.

How can I add different routes per store view in a custom module on a Magento 2.4 store, following the attached example?

EN: [www.domain.com/welcome/index/start](http://www.domain.com/welcome/index/start)
FR: [www.domain.com/bienvenue/index/start](http://www.domain.com/bienvenue/index/start)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Module name - **Vendor_CustomUrlRouter****

You have to create below listed files

**1. Registration.php :: app/code/Vendor/CustomUrlRouter/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_CustomUrlRouter', __DIR__

);
?>
```

**2. Module.xml :: app/code/Vendor/CustomUrlRouter/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">

    <module name="Vendor_CustomUrlRouter" setup_version="2.0.0"></module>

</config>
```

**3. di.xml :: app/code/Vendor/CustomUrlRouter/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
</config>
```

**4. routes.xml :: app/code/Vendor/CustomUrlRouter/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<router id="standard">

    <route id="aksurlrouter" frontName="aksurlrouter">

        <module name="Vendor_CustomUrlRouter" />

    </route>

</router>
```

**5. di.xml :: app/code/Vendor/CustomUrlRouter/etc/frontend/di.xml**

Here we need to passing the router file path and the sort order for the router

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">

        <arguments>

            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">

                <item name="akscustomurlrouter" xsi:type="array">

                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor/CustomUrlRouter\Controller\Router</item>

                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>

                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">61</item>

                </item>

            </argument>

        </arguments>

    </type>

</config>
```

**6.Routes.php :: app/code/Vendor/CustomUrlRouter/Controller/Router.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor/CustomUrlRouter\Controller;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface {

    /**

     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory

     */

    protected $actionFactory;

    /**

     * Response

     *

     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface

     */

    protected $_response;

    /**

     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory

     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response

     */

    public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response

    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;

        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validate and Match
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool
     */

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {

        /*

         * We can use any name of the URL to add and make condition for that name for redirect it. Here we can get customrouting 

         * If we got the same url it will redirect the request to controller action.

         * If we want to search “examplerouter” and “exampletocms” words to redirect the cutom router

         * using this example -examplerouter will forward to base router to match aksurlrouter front name, test the controller path and test controller class

         * -exampletocms will set for front name to cms, and controller path to page and action to view

         */

        //$a = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        //$postId = end($a);  [if you want to pass parameter also.]


        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if (strpos($identifier, 'exampletocms') !== false) {

            /* We must set module name, controller path and action name within need to set page id 5 witch is about us page on default magento 2 installation with sample data.
             */

            $request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('page')->setActionName('view')->setParam('page_id', 4); // specify the page id

        } else if (strpos($identifier, 'customrouting') !== false) {

            /* We must set module name, controller path and action name for our controller is class(Controller/Test/Test.php)
            */

            $request->setModuleName('CustomRouter')->setControllerName('test')->setActionName('test');

            // $request->setParam('id', $postId); [if passing params]

        } else {

            //If it is no match
            return;

        }

        /*

         * We have match and now we will forward action

         */
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
        );

    }
}

/* you will face iteration error if the controller is not available you have to trying to access*/
?>
```

**7. Test.php :: app/code/Vendor/CustomUrlRouter/Controller/Test/Test.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor/CustomUrlRouter\Controller\Test;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**

     * Listing all images in gallery

     *  -@param gallery id

     */
    public function execute() {

        die("Inchoo\\CustomRouter\\Controller\\Test\\Test controller execute()");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used StoreManagerInterface to determine the current store and in this way I could serve different pages from different URLs on each store view. However, it seems that the old URLs (the base route) is still working. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: In Steps 5 for disable change
<item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
to 
<item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>